# Vending Machine Project - Guidance on OOP code [Python]

Tags: python

Quite new to programming and have got an issue with some of my python code. I feel like there would be an easier way to write it/ simplify it. I am still working through it (working on the first item before and have got my 'tea' in the virtual vending machine. However I am not sure using that many if elif statements is the cleanest way to complete the code? Also, I want the code to constantly have an input available to the user so they can order more that one drink (if they have the money). So I would like it to loop and start again without losing the coin, how would I go about that?

I know it isn't much, but its my first assignment and I am happy that I have got it this far!

```
class Vending_Machine: 
aussie_coins = (0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1.00, 2.00)
items = ['Tea','Coffee', 'Coke', 'Orange Juice']
item_price = [0.50, 1.00, 1.50, 1.00]
item_code = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

def __init__(self): #define total in vending machine. 
    self.total = 0.00

def insert_coin(self,coin):
    if float(coin) not in (self.aussie_coins):
        print ('The Vending Machine accepts only: {}. ' .format(self.aussie_coins), end = '')
    else:
        self.total += coin
        print ('Currently there is a total of {: .2f} in machine' .format(self.total))

class interface(Vending_Machine):            
def menu(self):
    print("##################################")
    print(" Welcome to my Vending Machine ")
    print("All items below are readily available")
    print(Vending_Machine.item_code[0], Vending_Machine.items[0], "${: .2f}".format(Vending_Machine.item_price[0])) #
    print(Vending_Machine.item_code[1], Vending_Machine.items[1], "${: .2f}".format(Vending_Machine.item_price[1]))
    print(Vending_Machine.item_code[2], Vending_Machine.items[2], "${: .2f}".format(Vending_Machine.item_price[2]))
    print(Vending_Machine.item_code[3], Vending_Machine.items[3], "${: .2f}".format(Vending_Machine.item_price[3]))
    print("##################################")

class user_input(interface):
    def choice (self):
        choice = input("Please enter the item code of an item you would like to purchase: ")
        if choice == Vending_Machine.item_code[0]:
            print ("You have selected {} - the price is ${: .2f}. Currently you have a total of ${: .2f} in the machine." .format(Vending_Machine.items[0], Vending_Machine.item_price[0], self.total))
            if self.total < Vending_Machine.item_price[0]: 
                coins = float(input("Insert a coin into the vending machine: "))
                Vending_Machine.insert_coin(self,coins)
                if self.total == Vending_Machine.item_price[0]:
                    self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[0]
                    print('Please take your {}. There is currently ${: .2f} left in the Machine. Thanks, have a nice day!'.format(Vending_Machine.items[0], self.total))
                elif self.total > Vending_Machine.item_price[0]:
                    self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[0]
                    print ('Please take your {}. There is currently ${: .2f} left in the Machine. Thanks, have a nice day!'.format(Vending_Machine.items[0], self.total))
            elif self.total > Vending_Machine.item_price[0]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[0]
                print('Please take your {}. Total of {: .2f} in the machine' .format(Vending_Machine.items[0],self.total))
            elif self.total == Vending_Machine.item_price[0]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[0]
                print('Please take your {}. Thanks, have a nice day!'.format(Vending_Machine.items[0]))

        elif choice == Vending_Machine.item_code[1]:
            print ("You have selected {} - the price is ${: .2f}. Currently you have a total of ${: .2f} in the machine." .format(Vending_Machine.items[1], Vending_Machine.item_price[1], self.total))
            if self.total < Vending_Machine.item_price[1]: 
                insert_coin(input("Insert a coin into the vending machine: "))
            elif self.total > Vending_Machine.item_price[1]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[1]
                print('Please take your {}. Total of {: .2f} in the machine' .format(Vending_Machine.items[1],self.total))
            elif self.total == Vending_Machine.item_price[1]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[1]
                print('Please take your {}. Thanks, have a nice day!'.format(Vending_Machine.items[1]))

        elif choice == Vending_Machine.item_code[2]:
            print ("You have selected {} - the price is ${: .2f}. Currently you have a total of ${: .2f} in the machine." .format(Vending_Machine.items[2], Vending_Machine.item_price[2], self.total))
            if self.total < Vending_Machine.item_price[2]: 
                insert_coin(input("Insert a coin into the vending machine: "))
            elif self.total > Vending_Machine.item_price[2]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[2]
                print('Please take your {}. Total of {: .2f} in the machine' .format(Vending_Machine.items[2],self.total))
            elif self.total == Vending_Machine.item_price[2]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[2]
                print('Please take your {}. Thanks, have a nice day!'.format(Vending_Machine.items[2]))

        elif choice == Vending_Machine.item_code[3]:
            print ("You have selected {} - the price is ${: .2f}. Currently you have a total of ${: .2f} in the machine." .format(Vending_Machine.items[3], Vending_Machine.item_price[3], self.total))
            if self.total < Vending_Machine.item_price[3]: #if not the price of tea then.. 
                insert_coin(input("Insert a coin into the vending machine: "))
            elif self.total > Vending_Machine.item_price[3]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[3]
                print('Please take your {}. Total of {: .2f} in the machine' .format(Vending_Machine.items[3],self.total))
            elif self.total == Vending_Machine.item_price[3]:
                self.total -= Vending_Machine.item_price[3]
                print('Please take your {}. Thanks, have a nice day!'.format(Vending_Machine.items[3]))

            elif choice not in item_code:
                print("Sorry we do not have item number {} available. Please try again" .format(choice))  


vm = Vending_Machine()
i1 = interface()
u1 = user_input()

i1.menu()
u1.choice()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably better suited for the [code review board](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but anyways...
Really great for a first project! That being said, you've already identified the major shortcoming of your code - you shouldn't have to use all those `if`/`elif`s. I also don't think you can justify wrapping most of your code into classes, like you've done. These are my suggestions:

- Define two classes, `VendingMachine` and `Item` (an instance of this
  class represents a single available item in the vending machine).
- Follow good naming conventions. Notice the class names start with an
  uppercase letter, and are camel-case.
- Define an explicit entry point for your program, such as `main`.
- Use a loop to iterate over your vending machine items when displaying
  them. You can do something similar to cull all those if-statements.

Code:

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price


class VendingMachine:

    def __init__(self):

        self.items = [
            Item("Tea", 0.50),
            Item("Coffee", 1.00),
            Item("Coke", 1.50),
            Item("Orange Juice", 1.00)
        ]

        self.money_inserted = 0.00

    def display_items(self):
        for code, item in enumerate(self.items, start=1):
            print(f"[{code}] - {item.name} (${item.price:.2f})")

    def insert_money(self, money):
        if money <= 0.00:
            raise ValueError
        self.money_inserted += money

def main():

    vending_machine = VendingMachine()
    vending_machine.display_items()

    while True:
        try:
            user_selection = int(input("Please enter the desired item code: "))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if user_selection in range(1, len(vending_machine.items)+1):
            break
    item = vending_machine.items[user_selection-1]
    print(f"You've selected \"{item.name}\" - the price is ${item.price:.2f}")
    while vending_machine.money_inserted < item.price:
        print(f"You've inserted ${vending_machine.money_inserted:.2f} into the machine so far.")
        while True:
            try:
                money_to_insert = float(input("Please enter the amount of money you'd like to insert: "))
                vending_machine.insert_money(money_to_insert)
            except ValueError:
                continue
            else:
                break
    print(f"Thank you! Please take your \"{item.name}\".")
    print(f"The remaining change in the machine is ${vending_machine.money_inserted - item.price:.2f}.")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
[1] - Tea ($0.50)
[2] - Coffee ($1.00)
[3] - Coke ($1.50)
[4] - Orange Juice ($1.00)
Please enter the desired item code: d32
Please enter the desired item code: 3
You've selected "Coke" - the price is $1.50
You've inserted $0.00 into the machine so far.
Please enter the amount of money you'd like to insert: 4ff4
Please enter the amount of money you'd like to insert: 1
You've inserted $1.00 into the machine so far.
Please enter the amount of money you'd like to insert: .10
You've inserted $1.10 into the machine so far.
Please enter the amount of money you'd like to insert: .90
Thank you! Please take your "Coke".
The remaining change in the machine is $0.50.
>>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by:

Use a loop to iterate over your vending machine items when displaying them. You can do something similar to cull all those if-statements?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been working on a different angle. But I will post over on code review board, as you suggested. Thanks again for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Good work. I've got one word to say to you: loops.

Where you've got 4 lines printing the vending machine items (at the start), you could replace it with a loop, like so:

```py
for index in range(len(VendingMachine.items)):
  print(Vending_Machine.item_code[index], Vending_Machine.items[index], "${: .2f}".format(Vending_Machine.item_price[index]))
```

Hopefully that gives you enough information to work out how to shrink the rest of your code too. If it needs to be `elif` (as in, you only want to check one of them, not all of them), use a `break` in the loop (see below for an example of a break).

---

As for your second question, you could have a loop around the `insert_coin` function call (in the `user_input` function) which keeps adding coins until the user inputs 'done'.

Here's a pretty basic example. There could be better ways to do this, but it should work.

```py
while True:
  coins = float(input("Insert a coin into the vending machine: "))
  if coins == "done":
    break
  Vending_Machine.insert_coin(self,coins)
```